# afterRequest() method from AbstractReqestLoggingFilter accepts incomplete message text

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, logging, request

There is an implemented method of the `AbstractRegueestLoggingFilter` class called `afterRegueest`. It has two parameters: `HttpServletRequest request`, `String message`. For some reason, the `message` parameter comes incomplete, that is, cut off (there is a feeling that this message has a dimension, as is often the case with the size of `varhar` in the database). I don't understand how this can happen.

P.S. the message should display the information on the request that the client asks for. For example `Put: /api/url` and further the `request body`. I use it for logging.

So the body itself is cut off, and already at the input in the parameter.

How can I fix this problem?

```java
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) { // Here it is already incomplete !!!!!
        if (!FORBIDDEN_URLS.contains(request.getRequestURI())) {
            ApiRequestLog log = new ApiRequestLog();
            log.setMethod(RequestMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()).name());
            log.setUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            log.setParams(request.getQueryString());
            String body = StringUtils.substringAfter(message, "payload=");
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(body)) {
                log.setBody(body);
            }
            try {
                log.setCreatedBy(UserHelper.getUser());
            } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
            }
            try {
                queueService.sendToQueue(log, REQUESTS_FOR_SAVE);
            } catch (JMSException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we manually wrote into the code the maximum length of the request body that we could accept. In this regard, I just changed the maximum number of characters to a larger value.

```java
@Autowired
    public CustomLoggingFilter(QueueService queueService) {
        setIncludePayload(true);
        setMaxPayloadLength(2048);
        setBeforeMessagePrefix("");
        setBeforeMessageSuffix("");
        setAfterMessagePrefix("");
        setAfterMessageSuffix("");
        this.queueService = queueService;
    }
```

I change setMaxPayloadLength(2048) on 1million length value.